# Python: Need to use a file by name and either one of two extension

Tags: python, path, operating-system

```
path = "/test/"
file = "afile"
path = (path + '/' + file + ('.png' or '.jpg'))
```

Does test have `afile.jpg` or `afile.png` and use the one it has.

I know this is incorrect, but it sums up what I would like to do.

I have a file name (`file`) and want to added it to `path` and since I'm not sure if the file is a JPG or PNG I want to try both.

Obviously the above is not going to work. But I need a simple check. My solution required listing file directories for matches. There has to be a simple solution?

Comment: What are you planning to _do_ with these filenames? Are you going to `open` the file? Or print out the name as a string? Or…?

Answer (score 2):

Test if the file exists:

```
filename = os.path.join(path, file)
for extension in ('.png', '.jpg'):
    if os.path.isfile(filename + extension):
        filename += extension
        break
else:
    print 'File not found'
```

Comment: Or, better, just `try` to `open`/`Image.open`/whatever the first one, and `except FileNotFoundError:`, `try` the other one (or, for more generality, `try:` in a loop like this).

Comment: for some reason I wasn't getting a response when I tried file exists. it was defaulting to the else. I will try your code, maybe I messed something up

Comment: @Lunatixz: Then neither extension exists; are you certain you have the proper path?

Comment: @abarnert: Provided the OP actually wants to open the file. If you are going to use `shutil.move()` on it, for example, or list files in an XML document you are generating, etc. then there are different failure modes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try os.path again and I'll check to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, since we don't know what the OP actually wants these filenames for, it's hard to know the best thing to do. Which is why I asked him in a comment, and added this comment here despite upvoting your answer.

Comment: I'm working on a python plugin for xbmc, I'm trying to set a label and pass an image link to the plugins skin. Since in this example i'm not sure if a user has a jpg or png, I want to see which one exists and use one...